# Line Integral of vector force field

Tags: calculus

Find the work done by the force field $F(x,y)=x^2\vec{i}-xy\vec{j}$ in moving a particle along the quarter-circle $r(t)=\cos(t)\vec{i}+\sin(t)\vec{j}, 0\le t\le \pi/2$

Solution:

Since $x=\cos(t)$ and $y=\sin(t)$, we have

$F(r(t))=\cos^2(t)\vec{i}-\cos(t)\sin(t)\vec{j}$

and

$r'(t)=-\sin(t)\vec{i}+\cos(t)\vec{j}$

This is an example from a text book. Could someone please explain the steps in obtaining $F(r(t))$ and $r'(t)$. The text book doesn't show any steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain $F(r(t))$ by simply substituting $x=\cos(t)$ and $y=\sin(t)$, as you noted, in your original $F(x,y)$. This gives $F(r(t))=\cos^2(t)\vec{i}-\cos(t)\sin(t)\vec{j}$.

To find $r'(t)$, simply differentiate $r(t)$ term-by-term to find $r'(t)=-\sin(t)\vec{i}+\cos(t)\vec{j}$.

Once $F(r(t))$ and $r'(t)$ are known, calculating the line integral is simple:

$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\left(\cos^2(t)\vec{i}-\cos(t)\sin(t)\vec{j}\right)\cdot\left(-\sin(t)\vec{i}+\cos(t)\vec{j}\right)dt=-\frac{2}{3}$$

Comment: The result of a negative value for the net work is reasonable in that the trajectory of the particle advances counter-clockwise in the first quadrant of a circle of radius 1 (centered on the origin), while the field acts on the particle "to the right and downward".  So the motion of the particle is being _resisted_:  an initial amount of kinetic energy of the particle will be reduced as it moves.